# My hitbox doesn't get true location. How can I solve this?

Tags: python, pygame

Sorry for bad english :(

It's my get hitbox function:

```
def hitbox(self):
    return (self.x - 50,self.y - 50),(self.x + 50,self.y + 50)
```

I am using this for show hitbox:

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen,(122,122,0),(self.hitbox()[0],self.hitbox()[1]),3)
```

But my sprite when go to right, hitbox is getting more widht to right and
when go to down, hitbox is getting more height to down.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PyGame Rect](https://web.archive.org/web/20200203034147/https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect) takes four arguments `( x, y, width, height )`.  Your `hitbox()` function is returning a rectangle defined by `( x1, y1, x2, y2 )`.

Perhaps the best approach would be to return a [Rect](https://web.archive.org/web/20200203034147/https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect) from your function.  This will also allow you to use the excellent PyGame Rect [collision handling functions](https://web.archive.org/web/20200203034147/https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) too.

```
BOX_WIDTH  = 100
BOX_HEIGHT = 100

def hitbox(self):
     # Create the box at 0,0 with correct size
     box_rect = pygame.Rect( 0, 0, BOX_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT )
     # transpose it around the current position
     box_rect.center = ( self.x, self.y )
     return box_rect
```

And then draw the Rect:

```
pygame.draw.rect( screen, ( 122, 122, 0 ), self.hitbox(), 3 )
```

I think it would be a good idea to store the Rect as a member if of the class. Then to move the sprite, simply update the `self.box_rect` object directly.